# Маршрутизация между двумя локальными сетями

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация

Есть ПК 1 (Windows 10) в нем стоит 2 сетевые карты в первую идет интернет от провайдера и от нее раздает интернет на вторую сетевую карту, из нее провод идет в роутер(keenetic). А от роутера уже к портам подключен пк 2 и раздача wi-fi. Возможно ли вообще сделать так, чтобы ПК 1 мог видеть веб-интерфейс роутера (192.168.1.1) и например был доступ к устройствам из wi-fi сети?[image: Домашняя сеть]

Comment: А что, роутеры с WAN-портами для интернета перестали выпускать? Почему не воткнуть интернет туда, куда следует?)

Comment: @SelfishCrawler, Потому что прокладка кабелей уже была сделана так=) Да и более большая проблема это то, что роутер часто рвет соединение на пару секунд, а интернет напрямую в пк и все хорошо. Меньше узлов = меньше проблем.

Comment: Так почему вы на второй сетевой карте не пропишете подсеть роутера просто?

Comment: @SelfishCrawler, Если не затруднит можно на примере?  Мы прописываем на второй сетевой карте 192.168.1.100, а на роутере на порту пропишем 192.168.1.101 и шлюзом прописываем вторую сетевую карту. Если так то что-то не работает,  нет интернета у устройств которые подключены к роутеру=(

Comment: Вам нужно ввести вторую сетевую карту в подсеть роутера и прописать маршрут на этом ПК с помощью команды route. Думаю как-то так. Либо если в клиентской винде есть RRAS оснастка, настроить маршруты там.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Не совсем понимаю как ввести вторую сетевую карту в подсеть роутера.

Comment: Вписать в настройки адрес 192.168.1.x, затем в ОС добавить маршрут от 192.168.159.1/24 (или какой у вас там адрес первой сетевухи) к 192.168.1.1/24

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно ли вообще сделать так, чтобы ПК 1 мог видеть веб-интерфейс роутера (192.168.1.1)

99% что нет. Или у роутера есть серьёзные проблемы с безопасностью.

Однако веб-интерфейс будет доступен по WAN-адресу роутера (192.168.159.2) - если доступ к управлению через WAN разрешить в настройках роутера, конечно.

> был доступ к устройствам из wi-fi сети?

Нет. Можно разве что организовать доступ в определённому сервису определённого узла WiFi-сети соответствующим маппингом портов.

---

Впрочем, обе задачи можно решить, если не использовать роутерные возможности кинетика и эксплуатировать его в режиме прозрачного моста. Если он, конечно, это умеет.

Альтернативно можно подключить роутер не через WAN, а через LAN - в этом случае он будет работать не как роутер, а как коммутатор и конвертор интерфейса (нужно будет ещё отключить изолирование портов). И на роутере нужно будет отключить DHCP - эту функцию будет выполнять ПК1.

Comment: А если веб-интерфейс не доступен по WAN адресу роутера? И 192.168.159.2 даже не пингуется с ПК 1.

Comment: @ЛизаШустрая Значит, надо разрешить администрирование через WAN в настройках. Я ж написал об этом..

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае помогло вот что, на **ПК-1** прописать **маршрут** до сети **192.168.1.0/24** через шлюз **192.168.159.2**.

```
route add -p 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.159.2
```

А на **роутере** в межсетевом экране для интерфейса **LAN** добавить правило с адресом источника **192.168.159.1**.

На счет безопасности есть вопросы, как сказал **@Akina** если есть доступ до 192.168.1.1 то у роутера серьезные проблемы с безопасностью ( сейчас доступ есть и к роутеру и ко всем устройствам внутри сети с ПК-1 ), но есть вероятность что мы неправильно друг друга поняли=)